# Hash function for custom type

Tags: hash, types, julia

I'm trying to define a custom equality method for a new type I've constructed. This is a MWE getting at what I'm trying to do.

```
mutable struct a
    first_num::Int
    second_num::Int
end

import Base.==
import Base.hash
function hash(obj::a, h=33141651)
    return hash((obj.first_num, obj.second_num), h)
end

function ==(obj1::a, obj2::a)
    if hash(obj1) == hash(obj2)
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

a1 = a(2,3)
a2 = a(2,3)
a1 == a2
```

I then get an error like `ERROR: TypeError: ==: in typeassert, expected UInt64, got Int64`

Is h becoming Int64?

In addition, if hashing the tuple of attributes is simply not the correct way to do this, let me know.

Edit: Actually, I ran this and I'm getting `MethodError: no method matching hash(::Tuple{Int64,Int64}, ::Int64)`. Is `h` being promoted to Int64?

Comment: I hope you're not assuming that `hash(obj1) == hash(obj2)` means that `obj1 == obj2`, because that's just not true in the general case. Two objects can return the same hash code, but not be equal.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your literal value for `h` (33141651) is an `Int` rather than a `UInt`. Thus, when you call `hash` with the tuple `h` is an `Int`, but the internal tuple `hash` function expects a `UInt`. I don't think you have to specify a value for `h` at all, and something like this should be enough:

```
function Base.hash(obj::a, h::UInt)
    return hash((obj.first_num, obj.second_num), h)
end
```

Full example for completeness:

```
mutable struct A
    first::Int
    second::Int
end

function Base.hash(obj::A, h::UInt)
    return hash((obj.first, obj.second), h)
end

function Base.:(==)(obj1::A, obj2::A)
    return hash(obj1) == hash(obj2)
end
```

With the following behaviour

```
julia> a = A(2,3); b = A(2,3)
A(2, 3)

julia> hash(a)
0x965b43497b212144

julia> hash(b)
0x965b43497b212144

julia> a == b
true
```